# Quick mode negotiation failed - no policy configured - Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-web-services, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

I am establishing an IPSEC Tunnel from my office to Amazon Web Services VPC, using the windows 2008 R2 machine as the "customer gateway". I configured my machine using this guide [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/CustomerGateway-Windows.html).

However the Tunnels never get up. I dig deeper with AWS support to find that phase 1 of IPSEC Tunnel which is IKE association is mature and establishes well but the phase 2 or quick mode fails with the following error:

> quick mode negotiation failed - reason "no policy configured"

I checked this [official microsoft VPN IPSEC solutions guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb794765.aspx) which didnt fit to my scenario.

P.S.

I have configured windows 2008 r2 within EC2 instance to connect a AWS VPC in another region and it worked great! I am using same configurations as told by AWS but its not working in my office!

My Questions here are: 
1) What are all possibilities Phase 2 connection is not establishing? 
2) Help me identify this security event log "Quick mode negotiation failed - no policy configured "

Answer (score 0):

Phase2 refers to when the VPN endpoint exchange information about the protected LAN segments and the protocol to be used for encryption/authentication of these segments.

Typically, you have Phase2 error when:

1. the two VPN endpoint have different views of what should be routed inside the VPN
2. when the ENC/AUTH protocols do not match.

Let me do an example: suppose you have a first firewall (A) with LAN 192.168.1.0/24 and a second firewall (B) with LAN 192.168.2.0/24.

Firewall A has a VPN configured to firewall B, routing its LAN 192.168.1.0/24 inside VPN. At the same time, due to a configuration error, the remote LAN (B's LAN) is define as 192.168.3.0/24.

Firewall B, on the other side, is correctly configured: its LAN 192.168.2.0/24 is routed inside the VPN with remote LAN 192.168.1.0/24.

When firewall A will begin P2 negotiation, the second firewall (B) will complain with a P2 policy error, because it know nothing about the (misconfigured) 192.168.3.0/24 segment.

So, double check the networks routed inside VPN *and* the ENC/AUTH protocols used for Phase2.

Comment: But in my case i have a different subnet in both side, one is 132.0.0.0/16 and the other is 172.16.0.0/16 and this same config works fine at AWS region 1 to another region 2. And I double checked encapsulation & auth.. still no luck